# Error in expo Error: node_modules directory is missing. Please run `npm install

Tags: node.js, expo

I'm trying to visualize expo on my cell phone and start doing the application but it does not run and I get this error

```
[16:38:55] Using project at C:\Users\AURIS\AwesomeProject
[16:38:59] Error: node_modules directory is missing. Please run `npm install` in
 your project directory.
[16:38:59] Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project
.
[16:38:59] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Comment: Please run `npm install` in your project directory.

Comment: Are you try `expo init`?